# Could not start virtual device from eclipse

Tags: android

when I configured my Eclipse with ADT and SDK, I created a new android project, and then I right click the project name and select the Run As -> Android Application, but I got the error message in the console like this:

```
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Android] ------------------------------
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Android] Android Launch!
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Android] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Android] Performing com.android.Activity01 activity launch
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Android] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '2.1'
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Android] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '2.1'
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: by.
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-25 19:11:01 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

so, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I have Win 7 64b

I do 3 things.

1. Uninstall Android SDK from c://Program Files (x86)\ bla bla lba
2. Install Android SDK to c://Android/Sdk/blablaba
3. Reset the Eclipse path to SDK in Windows/Preference -> Andriod ->
   Browse Folder for SDK...

All things start to work. I guess that critical for SDK is to be installed in the folder with spaces in the Folder name.